# ClickTag - Different URL for the same clickTag

Tags: javascript, double-click-advertising, clicktag

So, I built a banner with clickTag.

I would like to know, **if it's possible to assign two landing pages for the same clickTag, and also make it work in the DoubleClick**.

One landing page should go to the desktop URL, one should go to the mobile URL.

I kinda managed to do this, **but for some reason the ad won't work correctly in DoubleClick**. When the ad is previewed with mobile-device and clicked, the desktop URL is still opened.

This is what I did:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">    
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
var clickTag1 = "https://m.google.com/fi/";
} else {
var clickTag1 = "https://www.google.com/fi/";
</script>

<a href="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag1)">Open clickTag</a>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is usually done through macros and utm codes. You just make the landing page smarter. In the past I've seen landing pages with code that redirects based on User Agent.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [DoubleClick Enabler](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/docs/sdk/html5/en/class_studio_Enabler.html), then you can create both exit URL's on the DoubleClick plataform and run the exit as follows:

`Enabler.exit("URL1");`

Or you can use `exitOverride`:

`Enabler.exitOverride("URL2", "http://www.bbc.com");`

Then you'll be able to see the URL's on the Doubleclick platform.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will take a look on this.